# My emit is not working with my async function in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, supabase, pinia

I have no clue on why my code is failing. I have a pinia store function that have to create a item in my supabase db and a component that is using the function. The component use the function and then have to send a emit to the parent component, so I use the async and await. The problem is that the emit is not been send. I know is not about the promise, because the console log is working fine, but the emit is not working.

When I remove the async and await of the component the emit works fine.

This is the pinia function

```js
async insertar_row(row) {
    const { data, error } = await this.supabase
        .from('provisiones')
        .insert([
            row,
        ])
        .select()
    console.log("Subida exitosa")
},
```

This is the component function where is the problem

```js
async function enviar_emit (){
    try{
        await useDBStore.insertar_row(data_entry)
            emits('saveModalProvision')
            console.log("Work")
    }
    catch{
        console.log('Errorrrrr')
    }
}
```

I need that the emit work only when the pinia function ends.

Comment: You've only shown how the emit is being called. Please also include how the emit is defined and also show how the parent component is listening for the emit's event.  We need see all relevant code related to the emit to understand where something has possibly gone wrong.